# setup friendly URL for SP Online site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, dns, sp-online

I am trying to setup friendly URL for SP Online site collection. For Example by default all SP Online site collections looks like  **http://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/test**

Here I don't want to have sharepoint.com in the URL instead I'm trying to setup something very friendly URL based on the projectname or business unit such as **https://projectname.companyname.com/test**

I don't have much experience on DNS setup. Can anyone please throw some light on this query that would be helpful.
Also is there any limitations/cons if I setup friendly URL like this **https://projectname.companyname.com/test**

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, in SharePoint On-Premises, AAM can be used to change the host name by adding DNS Entries. However as far as I know, there is no similar built-in function in SPO so far.